# How to include sort function into parsed table?

Tags: php, sorting, html-table, html-parsing

I want to sort a parsed html-table (via simple_html_dom) by two of its columns and for some part by a specific order before echoing it. Its the first column with `<th>pos</th>` and the `<td's>` containing "PG" "SG" "SF" "PF" and "C" for basketball positions. At a second level it should get sort by the 4th column containing the shot volume (th = 2ga
, td's are numeric)

This should be the order:

```
first priority: "pos" = 0 "PG" = 1 "SG" = 2 "SF" = 3 "PF" = 4 "C" = 5. 
second priority: "2ga" = 0, numbers descending, biggest value at first
```

I checked the various sort function php has to offer, but I'm honestly a little bit overwhelmed by the depth of it since I'm kinda new to php. Here an example of the source code:

```
    <table><hr>
        <tr><th>po</th><th>player</th><th>age</th><th>2ga</th><th>2g%</th><th>fta</th><th>ft%</th><th>3ga</th><th>3g%</th><th>orb</th><th>drb</th><th>ast</th><th>stl</th><th>to</th><th>blk</th><th>o-o</th><th>d-o</th><th>p-o</th><th>t-o</th><th>o-d</th><th>d-d</th><th>p-d</th><th>t-d</th></tr>
        <tr><td CLASS=tdp>PG</td><td CLASS=tdp>James Harden</td><td>27</td><td>48</td><td>53</td><td>95</td><td>85</td><td>85</td><td>35</td><td>20</td><td>59</td><td>99</td><td>57</td><td>1</td><td>12</td><td>4</td><td>9</td><td>7</td><td>9</td><td>8</td><td>6</td><td>5</td><td>7</td></tr>
        <tr><td CLASS=tdp>PG</td><td CLASS=tdp>Dennis Schroder</td><td>23</td><td>68</td><td>49</td><td>32</td><td>85</td><td>39</td><td>34</td><td>10</td><td>25</td><td>65</td><td>42</td><td>35</td><td>6</td><td>8</td><td>8</td><td>2</td><td>6</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>6</td></tr>
        <tr><td CLASS=tdp>SG</td><td CLASS=tdp>Evan Fournier</td><td>24</td><td>46</td><td>49</td><td>39</td><td>81</td><td>53</td><td>36</td><td>12</td><td>23</td><td>29</td><td>41</td><td>61</td><td>1</td><td>7</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>6</td></tr>
         ... more rows ...
        </table>
```

I'm stuck currently at this point. I especially don't know where I would have to put the sort function.

```
$table = $html->find('table', 1);
$rowData = array();

    // Loop
    foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {

// initialize array to store the cell data from each row
    $roster = array();
        foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
        // push the cell's text to the array
    $roster[] = $cell->innertext;
    }
    foreach($row->find('th') as $cell) {
        // push the cell's text to the array
     $roster[] = $cell->innertext;
}
        $rowData[] = $roster;
    }
        echo '<table>';
        foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($tr as $td)
            echo '<td>' . $td .'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
```

One possible sort function working the source html-code:

```
$rowData = $str;
$str = preg_replace('/\s{1,}/', ' ', $str);

preg_match_all('/<tr>(.*?)<\/tr>/', $str, $rows);
foreach($rows[1] as $row){

preg_match_all('/<td(.*?)<\/td>/', $row, $data);
$results[] = $data[0];
}

unset($results[0]);

array_walk_recursive($results, function(&$a, $b){
$a = strip_tags($a);
$a = trim($a);
});

$results = array_values($results);
for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++){
  switch($results[$i][0]){
    case 'PG':
    $results[$i][0] = 1;
    break;

    case 'SG':
    $results[$i][0] = 2;
    break;

    case 'SF':
    $results[$i][0] = 3;
    break;

    case 'PF':
    $results[$i][0] = 4;
    break;

    case 'C':
    $results[$i][0] = 5;
    break;
  }
}

usort($results, function($a, $b){
  if([$a[0], $a[4]] < [$b[0], $b[4]]){
    return 1;
  }elseif([$a[0], $a[4]] > [$b[0], $b[4]]){
    return -1;
    }else{
      return 0;
    }
});

for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++){
  switch($results[$i][0]){
    case 1:
    $results[$i][0] = 'PG';
    break;

    case 2:
    $results[$i][0] = 'SG';
    break;

    case 3:
    $results[$i][0] = 'SF';
    break;

    case 4:
    $results[$i][0] = 'PF';
    break;

    case 5:
    $results[$i][0] = 'C';
    break;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add example code?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: You say "parsed html-table"; are you trying to parse an HTML table of these stats (e.g. with `SimpleXML` or `DOMDocument`), do something it with PHP, and print it out again? Or are you generating the HTML table from PHP?

Comment: Currently with simple_html_dom.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, the expected result and the result you're currently getting.

Comment: You'll probably want to use `usort()` on your array of player data, and provide a callback function which compares the stats in the order of precedence that you care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

You have to loop through the $results array and then loop through each players results to output the data like you want.  This should work.

```
 $str =  "<table><hr>
<tr><th>po</th><th>player</th><th>age</th><th>2ga</th><th>2g%</th><th>fta</th><th>ft%</th><th>3ga</th><th>3g%</th><th>orb</th><th>drb</th><th>ast</th><th>stl</th><th>to</th><th>blk</th><th>o-o</th><th>d-o</th><th>p-o</th><th>t-o</th><th>o-d</th><th>d-d</th><th>p-d</th><th>t-d</th></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>PG</td><td CLASS=tdp>James Harden</td><td>27</td><td>48</td><td>53</td><td>95</td><td>85</td><td>85</td><td>35</td><td>20</td><td>59</td><td>99</td><td>57</td><td>1</td><td>12</td><td>4</td><td>9</td><td>7</td><td>9</td><td>8</td><td>6</td><td>5</td><td>7</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>PG</td><td CLASS=tdp>Dennis Schroder</td><td>23</td><td>68</td><td>49</td><td>32</td><td>85</td><td>39</td><td>34</td><td>10</td><td>25</td><td>65</td><td>42</td><td>35</td><td>6</td><td>8</td><td>8</td><td>2</td><td>6</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>SG</td><td CLASS=tdp>Evan Fournier</td><td>24</td><td>46</td><td>49</td><td>39</td><td>81</td><td>53</td><td>36</td><td>12</td><td>23</td><td>29</td><td>41</td><td>61</td><td>1</td><td>7</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>SG</td><td CLASS=tdp>Jamal Murray</td><td>19</td><td>39</td><td>47</td><td>21</td><td>88</td><td>63</td><td>33</td><td>14</td><td>29</td><td>30</td><td>42</td><td>61</td><td>13</td><td>7</td><td>5</td><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>3</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>SF</td><td CLASS=tdp>Luol Deng</td><td>31</td><td>32</td><td>43</td><td>13</td><td>73</td><td>36</td><td>31</td><td>27</td><td>48</td><td>16</td><td>45</td><td>82</td><td>13</td><td>5</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>1</td><td>7</td><td>6</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>SF</td><td CLASS=tdp>Dante Cunningham</td><td>29</td><td>19</td><td>58</td><td>5</td><td>59</td><td>36</td><td>39</td><td>21</td><td>41</td><td>7</td><td>33</td><td>90</td><td>17</td><td>8</td><td>2</td><td>4</td><td>1</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>PF</td><td CLASS=tdp>Thomas Robinson</td><td>25</td><td>55</td><td>54</td><td>32</td><td>47</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>83</td><td>67</td><td>15</td><td>57</td><td>55</td><td>14</td><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>9</td><td>1</td><td>9</td><td>5</td><td>9</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>PF</td><td CLASS=tdp>Ryan Kelly</td><td>24</td><td>38</td><td>45</td><td>32</td><td>69</td><td>23</td><td>14</td><td>25</td><td>58</td><td>12</td><td>34</td><td>79</td><td>19</td><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>7</td><td>1</td><td>7</td><td>4</td><td>6</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp> C</td><td CLASS=tdp>Dewayne Dedmon</td><td>27</td><td>33</td><td>62</td><td>20</td><td>70</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>57</td><td>79</td><td>10</td><td>36</td><td>73</td><td>43</td><td>5</td><td>3</td><td>9</td><td>1</td><td>8</td><td>5</td><td>9</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp> C</td><td CLASS=tdp>Robert Sacre</td><td>26</td><td>38</td><td>41</td><td>33</td><td>66</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td>34</td><td>12</td><td>15</td><td>80</td><td>28</td><td>1</td><td>4</td><td>7</td><td>3</td><td>5</td><td>2</td><td>7</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>SG</td><td CLASS=tdp>Vince Carter</td><td>40</td><td>19</td><td>42</td><td>20</td><td>77</td><td>54</td><td>38</td><td>12</td><td>33</td><td>23</td><td>47</td><td>83</td><td>20</td><td>7</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>3</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>SF</td><td CLASS=tdp>Nicolas Brussino</td><td>23</td><td>13</td><td>50</td><td>11</td><td>77</td><td>51</td><td>31</td><td>27</td><td>34</td><td>24</td><td>39</td><td>74</td><td>13</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>6</td><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>PF</td><td CLASS=tdp>Drew Gooden</td><td>34</td><td>31</td><td>42</td><td>12</td><td>64</td><td>38</td><td>17</td><td>50</td><td>49</td><td>11</td><td>31</td><td>77</td><td>31</td><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>1</td><td>6</td><td>3</td><td>7</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>";

$str = preg_replace('/\s{1,}/', ' ', $str);

preg_match_all('/<tr>(.*?)<\/tr>/', $str, $rows);

foreach($rows[1] as $row){

  preg_match_all('/<td(.*?)<\/td>/', $row, $data);

  $results[] = $data[0];

}

$header = $rows[0][0]; //<----Added this.

unset($results[0]);

array_walk_recursive($results, function(&$a, $b){

$a = strip_tags($a);

$a = trim($a);


});

$results = array_values($results);

for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++){

  switch($results[$i][0]){

    case 'PG':
    $results[$i][0] = 1;
    break;

    case 'SG':
    $results[$i][0] = 2;
    break;

    case 'SF':
    $results[$i][0] = 3;
    break;

    case 'PF':
    $results[$i][0] = 4;
    break;

    case 'C':
    $results[$i][0] = 5;
    break;

  }

}


usort($results, function($a, $b){

  if([$a[0], $a[4]] < [$b[0], $b[4]]){

    return 1;

  }elseif([$a[0], $a[4]] > [$b[0], $b[4]]){

    return -1;

    }else{

      return 0;

    }

});

for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++){

  switch($results[$i][0]){

    case 1:
    $results[$i][0] = 'PG';
    break;

    case 2:
    $results[$i][0] = 'SG';
    break;

    case 3:
    $results[$i][0] = 'SF';
    break;

    case 4:
    $results[$i][0] = 'PF';
    break;

    case 5:
    $results[$i][0] = 'C';
    break;

  }

}

 echo
'<table>';

echo $header; //<--Changed to this.

foreach($results as $key){

  echo
  '<tr>';

    foreach($key as $k=>$v){

      echo
      '<td>' . $v . '</td>';

    }

  echo
  '</tr>';

}

echo
'</table>';
```

Comment: Thank you. There are two things: 1] column 0 should be sorted by a defined order: PG = 1 | SG = 2 | SF = 3 | PF = 4 | C = 5. Right now it doesn't reponse to a position change e.g. of Harden from PG to C, which should bring him behind Schroder. But the part with the column 4 works fine. 2] Where to put it in my base code?

Comment: can you give me a larger sample of data to work with

Comment: Of course. Edited the question. As you see at the end of the table, there are some players which should be sorted up to the other players with the same position. And all players with the same position should be sorted by column 4.

Comment: @Chris I updated my answer.  See if that helps.. I'm still a little sketchy on the sort order for the pos.  This update does preserve the relationship that you posted though.

Comment: @Chris  I made a mistake in my code.  I have updated the code with the new edits..  I switched the order of the striptags and trim functions. I posted the new results also.  Let me know.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. With the html code it seems to work. But I can't include it correctly in the php code posted above. Do you know where to put it? I tried before the `echo '<table>` code, but getting a bunch of errors.

Comment: @Chris  Hey no problem, I updated the answer, it should work for you.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for accepting answer.  I added some extra code to populate the header so it's not hard coded in.  I updated code.  Look for where I made changes.  Only two lines.  Cheers